# Javascript Recursion with helper function

Tags: javascript

I have this chunk of code and I want to print this out.

```
a
  |->b
  |->c
     |->e
```

It works when I use
`let spaceStr = " ".repeat(level) + "|->";`
but not when I use the helper function `getSpace`.
It only prints the following:

```
a
    |->b
```

I cannot figure out why. Can someone explain to me?

```js
const obj = 
      { name: 'a', children: 
        [ { name: 'b', children: [] } 
        , { name: 'c', children: 
            [ { name: 'e', children: [] } 
            ] 
          } 
        ] 
      } 

function getSpace(level){
  var str = '';
  for (i=0; i < level; i++){
    str += '      ';
  }
  str += '|->';
  return str
}

function getPath(obj, level) {
  let result = [];
  let resultString = '';   
  let spaceStr = " ".repeat(level) + "|->";
//  let spaceStr = getSpace(level);
  
  if (obj.children.length === 0) {
      return spaceStr+obj.name;
  } else {
    
    if (level === 0) {
      result.push(obj.name);
    } else {
      result.push(spaceStr + obj.name);
    }
    for (i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++){   
      result.push(getPath(obj.children[i], level+1));

    }
  }
  return result;

}

function printPath(result){
    for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    console.log(result[i]);
  }
  return
}

printPath(getPath(obj,0).flat());
```

Comment: You're overwriting the value of `i` in the loop inside `getSpace`; you need to declare `i` local to each function

Answer (score 0):

By using `i=0` in your loops, you're not scoping the variable `i` correctly to the loop. Instead, it will bubble up to the closest instance of that variable name (until it hits the global scope). Consider using `let i = 0` in your loops to properly scope the variable. See the following functioning code:

```js
const obj = {
    "name": "a",
    "children": [{
            "name": "b",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "c",
            "children": [{
                "name": "e",
                "children": []
            }]
        }
    ]
}

function getSpace(level){
  var str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < level; i++){
    str += '      ';
  }
  str += '|->';
  return str
}

function getPath(obj, level) {
  let result = [];
  let resultString = '';   
  //let spaceStr = " ".repeat(level) + "|->";
  let spaceStr = getSpace(level);
  
  if (obj.children.length === 0) {
      return spaceStr+obj.name;
  } else {
    
    if (level === 0) {
      result.push(obj.name);
    } else {
      result.push(spaceStr + obj.name);
    }
    for (let i = 0;i<obj.children.length;i++){   
      result.push(getPath(obj.children[i], level+1));

    }
  }
  return result;

}

function printPath(result){
    for (let i = 0;i<result.length;i++){
    console.log(result[i]);
  }
  return
}

printPath(getPath(obj,0).flat());
```